# .cpp digit format for output

Tags: c++, io, output

How can I get the output in a .cpp program to display an integer as always two digits even if it's the number 1.  In that case, I'd need the output be "01".  My question doesn't apply to converting 3 or more digit numbers into 2 digits.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw

Comment: @NeilKirk I don't think `setw` adds leading zeros.

Comment: @vsoftco You are right, need to combine with http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill

Comment: Yeah, so basically you need `std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << 1;`

Comment: Avoid answering questions in comments.. @vsoftco

Comment: @MaheshBansod Yes I know, however I felt like this was a very simple answer (more of a comment really), but anyway I now posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is:

```
std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << 1;
```